# Spring doesn't set expiration time for records on Redis cache

Tags: java, spring, redis

I have the project where I send Objects to Redis cache, but Spring doesn't set expiration time for records. I tried in many ways:

1. By setting `@TimeToLive` annotation to field.
2. By adding `@RedisHash(timeToLive = 60)`.
3. By adding  `spring.cache.redis.time-to-live: 6000` to properties.

   ```
   @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    @Generated
    @RedisHash(timeToLive = 60)
    public class GetPackages extends GetPackagesType implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3086056567387275373L;
        private int BID;
        @TimeToLive
        Long ttl = 120L;
    }
   ```

But `redis-cli` says there is no TTL set for mykey.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6378> TTL mykey  
(integer) -1
```

I use:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I tried with 2.3.11.RELEASE, but it's the same.

I use dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you solve it?